# Displaying publication lists in a custom unsubscribe page

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am creating a custom unsubscribe page.

I would like to show the list of available publication lists in the cloud page. Not sure how to retrieve that information.

Please let me know if you have any pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A few options depending on which you prefer.

**Ampscript**

```
%%[
var @rr, @sfp, @lists, @status
SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rr,"ObjectType","List")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ListName")

SET @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp,"Property","Type")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp,"Value","Public")

SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@sfp)

SET @lists = InvokeRetrieve(@rr, @status)
]%%
```

**SSJS**

```
<script runat="server">
    var lists = List.Retrieve({Property:"Type",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Public"});
    Platform.Response.Write(Stringify(lists));
</script>
```

**SSJS WSProxy**

```
<script runat="server">
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var queryAllAccounts = true; // with this set it will query child BUs as well
    var cols = ["Client.ID","CustomerKey","ListName","ID"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "ListClassification",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "PublicationList"
    };
    var lists = prox.retrieve("List", cols, filter, queryAllAccounts);

    Platform.Response.Write(Stringify(lists));
</script>
```

Related documentation:

- [SSJS list retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_listRetrieve.htm)
- [Ampscript invoke retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/invokeretrieve.htm)
- [WSProxy basic retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.htm)
- [List SOAP Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/list.htm)

**Note**: ensure the "Public" attribute is checked on your publication list settings if you are using that for your filter, otherwise use ListClassification=PublicationList.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the code, it return an empty list. ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.APIObject[]. Do I need to pass the MID of the child BU as well?

Comment: Original question didn't mention child BU, but have added method that uses WSProxy and can search child BUs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The original code worked. I was not traversing the array correctly. In the code I changed List.ListName to Listname.

Comment: Great. I'll update the ampscript code.